# taking these soldiers to fight our enemies

Tags: meaning, infinitives

a. I am taking these soldiers to fight our enemies.

What is the implied agent of 'to fight'.

Are they going to fight our enemies or am I going to fight our enemies by using the soldiers?

Comment: The cited text could correspond to EITHER *I'm taking them **to help me** fight our enemies* OR  *I'm taking them **so they can** fight our enemies*. The unstated "subject" of ***to fight*** is thus ambiguous, and to some extent context-determined.

Answer (score 2):

It's ambiguous and only occasionally can be determined from the context.

Usually this ambiguity is unimportant and possibly intentional. It's clear the soldiers will fight the enemy, but whether the speaker will be fighting alongside them (say, as a commander) or only perform the transport (say, a helicopter pilot) can only be determined from the context.

It's the same ambiguity as the lack of [clusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clusivity) of "we" in English - "We're going" may mean "me and others are going, you stay" or "you and I are going."